# How can I have a listview item that only has a webview in it?

Tags: java, android, listview, webview

I couldn't find any way to do it. I need a listview item that is just a webview. Any ideas on how i can do this?

Comment: Out of the box this sounds like a bad idea. Perhaps if you elaborated on your use case it will make it easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: The only reason is that i want to be able to justify the text on that item.

Comment: Why don't you use a TextView inside a ListView item and set the TextView text with Html.fromHtml("htmlcode here") ? That will be lighter than using a WebView.

Answer (score 2):

You should never do this. First it would be a ScrollView inside a ScrollView which can seriously mess with scrolling. And secondly the WebView is a huge object and requires a high amount of memory. You should never use a WebView inside a ListView as there could be many WebView instances around at the same time which will consume a high amount of memory therefore increasing load times and this will make the list scrolling sluggish and unresponsive.

You can display simple html content with a TextView, like this:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlContent));
```